# Big-O of a multi-threading project

Tags: multithreading, time-complexity, code-complexity

Let's suppose that I create a project with 2 threads.
The Big O of them are  **n!** and **n** respectively and they run at the same time.

When one of them returns what I want, both of them stops. 
With that said, it would make sense that the complexity of the algorithm is **O(n)**, although one of the threads has a Big-O of **n!**, am I right?

P.S. I did my research but none of the answers serve my need, since all of them talk about a problem that is cut in half (*O(n/2)* per thread instead of *O(n)* with one thread), while I want to start solving 2 problems at once but both stop when the first one is done.

Comment: Your reasoning is only correct, surely, if you are certain that the `O(n)` thread will stop first.  If not, the complexity is `O(n!)` (which is the same complexity class as `O(n!/2)` ).

Comment: I think you're right. The complexity of the two threads together is `min(O(n), O(n!))` which, as `n` gets large, is `O(n)`.

Comment: Re, "O(n/2)".  That is not valid big O notation.  If the time complexity of your algorithm is "O(n)", and you find an improvement that cuts the running time by half, then the time complexity still is O(n) because the actual running time still is a linear function of _n_. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example

Comment: @SolomonSlow that was my point, O(n/2) equals O(n) so it makes no difference.

Comment: I would be more inclined to say that "O(n/2)" is an invalid expression, and therefore it doesn't "equal" anything...  But then I'm kind of picky about mathematical formalism.  IMO that's justified because really, math isn't anything _but_ formalism.

Comment: O(n/2) is a perfectly valid notation, it equals the same set of functions as O(n) does. It's just not in its simplest form; compare e.g. the fraction 6/4 and the fraction 3/2, neither of which are invalid notation but one of which is simpler.

Comment: @kaya3 I've never said it's invalid. I said it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The comment immediately above mine says *"I would be more inclined to say that "O(n/2)" is an **invalid** expression"* and two comments above that says *"That is **not valid** big O notation"* (emphasis mine). I responded to that to say that it is not invalid.

Answer (score 2):

The analysis of this needs to be more careful.

---

The thread scheduler may not guarantee that all threads will get a "fair" amount of execution time. Imagine two threads that are both counting up from 1, but the thread scheduler wakes thread A up for 1 step, then B for 1 step, then A for 2 steps, then B for 1 step, then A for 4 steps, and so on.

Thread A will do exponentially more work than thread B in this case, because it is given exponentially more time by the scheduler to do its work. So if thread B signals for thread A to stop after B counts up to n, then thread A would stop after counting up to 2<sup>n</sup> - 1. The scheduler could be even more unfair, so A's running time cannot be bounded by *any* function of n.

Given that, if thread A chooses to terminate itself after n! operations, then its running time can only be bounded by O(n!), because we can't *guarantee* that thread B will have completed its n operations and sent the termination signal within that time.

---

Now suppose the thread scheduler *does* guarantee that one thread is never favoured over another by more than some constant factor. In this case, the algorithm in thread B will send a signal to thread A after thread B completes O(n) steps. Since thread A can only complete O(n) steps in the same time (otherwise it would be favoured over thread B by more than a constant factor), then thread A will terminate in O(n) time.

That said, the fact that the algorithm in thread A is checking for a signal and terminating when it receives that signal, implies that O(n!) can't be derived as a *tight* upper bound just by looking at what thread A does; because it has instructions to terminate when it receives a signal from outside. So at least, there isn't a contradiction.